# Send expression to website return dynamic result (picture)

Tags: r, rcurl

I use http://www.regexper.com to view a picto representation regular expressions a lot.  I would like a way to ideally:

1. send a regular expression to the site
2. open the site with that expression displayed

For example let's use the regex: `"\\s*foo[A-Z]\\d{2,3}"`.  I'd go tot he site and paste `\s*foo[A-Z]\d{2,3}` (note the removal of the double slashes).  And it returns:

[image]

I'd like to do this process from within R.  Creating a wrapper function like `view_regex("\\s*foo[A-Z]\\d{2,3}")` and the page (http://www.regexper.com/#%5Cs*foo%5BA-Z%5D%5Cd%7B2%2C3%7D) with the visual diagram would be opened with the default browser.

I think RCurl may be appropriate but this is new territory for me.  I also see the double slash as a problem because http://www.regexper.com expects single slashes and R needs double.  I can get R to return a single slash to the console using `cat` as follows, so this may be how to approach.

```
x <- "\\s*foo[A-Z]\\d{2,3}"

cat(x)
\s*foo[A-Z]\d{2,3}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `URLencode`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Query <- function(searchPattern, browse = TRUE) {
  finalURL <- paste0("http://www.regexper.com/#", 
         URLencode(searchPattern))
  if (isTRUE(browse)) browseURL(finalURL)
  else finalURL
}

x <- "\\s*foo[A-Z]\\d{2,3}"
Query(x)             ## Will open in the browser
Query(x, FALSE)      ## Will return the URL expected
# [1] "http://www.regexper.com/#%5cs*foo[A-Z]%5cd%7b2,3%7d"
```

---

The above function simply pastes together the web URL prefix (`"http://www.regexper.com/#"`) and the encoded form of the search pattern you want to query.

After that, there are two options:

- Open the result in the browser
- Just return the full encoded URL

Comment: @Anando.  Perfect.  I see the magic is in `URLencode`.  I need to pick apart your individual pieces and understand more.  Thanks. +1

Comment: @TylerRinker, it's actually pretty straightforward. I had just stuck a `browse` argument in there for fun. I was looking for a way to get to the SVG too, but that's a bit more tricky.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I was going to suggest something with phantomjs but I am not sure it is worth the trouble.